# showing Count down timer in a label objective c

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I am new to IOS.I want to user countdown timer.I mean If it set timer for 5 min then after 5 min a function should call so I am using NSTimer for that and I will show min and seconds in a label so after 5 min the label will start from 0 min so it is perfectly working when my app is in foreground when when my app go to background NSTimer will not work after 3 min so when ever I am going I am background I am save time and second in NSUserDefault  and I am assigning that values to label when it comes to foreground but the timer is not showing perfectly

```js
-(void) StartTimer
{
    
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    
}

- (void)timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    timeSec++;
    if (timeSec >= 60)
    {
        timeSec = timeSec-60;
        timeMin++;
        
    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        [self StopTimer];
    //    }
    //Format the string 00:00
    
    NSString* timeNow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", timeMin, timeSec];
    
    //Display on your label
    //[timeLabel setStringValue:timeNow];
    
    
    
    self.lblForTimer.text= timeNow;
    NSNumber *numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[user.timerInterval intValue]];
    
    if (timeMin>= [numberValue intValue])
    {
        
        timeMin = 0;
        
        timeSec++;
    }
    
}


//Call this to stop the timer event(could use as a 'Pause' or 'Reset')
- (void) StopTimer
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer=nil;
    timeSec = 0;
    timeMin = 0;
    //Since we reset here, and timerTick won't update your label again, we need to refresh it again.
    //Format the string in 00:00
    NSString* timeNow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", timeMin, timeSec];
    //Display on your label
    // [timeLabel setStringValue:timeNow];
    self.lblForTimer.text= timeNow;
    
    
}
```

```js
- (void)appWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"will enter foreground notification");
    
    
    
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"did enter backgroun  notification");
    NSLog(@"%d,%d",timeMin,timeSec);
    NSDate *currentDate= [NSDate date];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentDate forKey:@"backgroundDate"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:timeSec forKey:@"sec"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:timeMin forKey:@"min"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    
    
    
    [self StopTimer];
    
}
```

```js
 - (void)appDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
                             NSDate *dateWhenAppGoesBg= (NSDate *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"backgroundDate"];
    NSTimeInterval timeSpentInBackground = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dateWhenAppGoesBg];
    int timeMinBack=floor(timeSpentInBackground/60);
    int timeSecBack=round(timeSpentInBackground - timeMinBack * 60);
    NSLog(@"%d%d",timeMinBack,timeSecBack);
    //    timeMin=(int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"min"]+timeMinBack;
    timeMin=[user.counterValue intValue];
//    timeSec=(int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"sec"]+timeSecBack;
    if (timeMin>0) {
        timeSec=timeSecBack;
    }
    else
    {
         timeSec=(int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"sec"]+timeSecBack;
    }
    NSLog(@"timme sec %d",timeSec);
    
    [self StartTimer];
}
```

this is my code for implementing countdown timer its perfectly working in foreground but when it comes to forground from background timer values is nit perfect there is 1 min of gap between timer cananyone help me out in this issue

Comment: OK, correct this first: represent time in seconds only, not minutes *and* seconds.  This makes manipulation easier.  When it comes to presentation of that remaining time then format it to minutes/seconds then and then only.

Answer (score 0):

You can save currentDate as property. Don't need to use NSUserDefaults in this case.

Save and manipulate your timeout just in seconds and when needed retranslate as so:

```
NSInteger min = self.timeout / 60;
NSInteger sec = self.timeout % 60;
```